# Getting exception when trying to set the status of GTalk using XMPPClient

Tags: android

I want to change the status of my gtalk using my application. For that i am using smack API and XMPPClient. But I am getting exception at the time of set the connection. Here is my code:

```
try
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration conn = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",Integer.parseInt("5222"),"gmail.com");
        Log.d("Debug", "configuration object has been created");
        conn.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        conn.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        m_xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(conn);
        m_xmppConnection.connect();
        Log.d("Debug", "try to connect using XMPPConnection");
        m_xmppConnection.login("yyy", "xxx");
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setStatus("Setting the status Programmatically");
        presence.setPriority(24);
        presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
        m_xmppConnection.sendPacket(presence);

    }

    catch(XMPPException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using Android 2.2 and added the smack 3.2.1 jar file. It is giving No response from server.

This is the error in logcat.

```
     11-15 18:40:28.301: W/System.err(7865): Connection failed. No response from server.: 
11-15 18:40:28.311: W/System.err(7865):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:120)
11-15 18:40:28.311: W/System.err(7865):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:606)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:565)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:991)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at com.innominds.ui.Notification.setStatusGtalk(Notification.java:519)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at com.innominds.ui.Notification.onClick(Notification.java:238)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-15 18:40:28.320: W/System.err(7865):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 18:40:28.343: W/System.err(7865):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-15 18:40:28.351: W/System.err(7865):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-15 18:40:28.351: W/System.err(7865):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why i am getting this can anyone please tell or help??

Comment: I added the logcat error. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clear execution which i see is like, you are doing the login and very soon after that you are setting the presence and staus, which is invalid. so it will definitely give you the error. you need to wait till login process has been completed and after that you can set the presence or status

try with try with "www.gmail.com" or "https://www.gmail.com"

Comment: actually it is not creating ConnectionConfiguration object. In the first line i am getting the exception.

Comment: I think for android you need to give the Port number also for configuration which is 5222

Comment: Yes, I changed the code. But now i am getting different exception.11-23 17:42:58.794: W/System.err(9885): XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.

Comment: 5222 port should be open for the connection please check that

Comment: How can i check that it is open or not??

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-i-can-view-what-ports-are-open/9829edab-c43c-4caf-ae5d-acf62155a580

Comment: Now i am using port 443. But still it is not working.11-15 18:33:36.240: W/System.err(7645): Connection failed. No response from server.:

Comment: Actually it is not your answer that resolved the problem. Any how thanks for the support.